# Simulate DS2401 with ATmega32?

Tags: avr, atmega, 1-wire, codevision

I have a **DS2401** and an **ATmega32**.

I can read the its contents with my *AVR* micro-controller.

I want to know, Is it possible to simulate the DS2401 with my ATmega32? I mean is it possible to connect atmega32 to a third-party master instead of the DS2401? if yes, how?

I myself think I must connect the master [third-party] to a interrupt pin of micro-controller and wait for a initial signal from master, is that right? What next?

Can anybody give me guidance?

- DS2401 Datasheet: http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2401.pdf
- ATmega32 Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2503.pdf

Comment: What's a DS2401?  Links please for those of us (all of us) who are too lazy to ask google.

Comment: :) links attache by dear John Meachan. Thank you dear John :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can replace your DS2410 by something else that behave like the DS2410.

Use another AtMega32, because you seem familiar with it, and connect one IO of it to the 1-wire bus.

Remember than the 1-wire bus requires open-drain masters and slaves. Thus you will control your 1-wire pin by switching between *output low* and *input* instead of *output low* and *output high*.

In all case you will have to write a custom firmware for that additional AtMega to instruct it to behave like a DS2410.

Comment: Thank you dear friend. Should I send the data bit by bit or byte by byte? would you please explain more detailed and as simplest as possible? :) did you mean : I must set the pin as a input and wait for a initial signal from master, and when I receive it a set the pin as output and set it low?! if I want to send a 1 bit what shall I do? thank you very much

Comment: If would be to difficult to explain here in detail. And the Stackexchange format is not suited to this. I suggest that you look at the end of the datasheet of a 1-Wire chip. The waveform is probably shown with all the timing. Then you will have to write a piece of software that does this. How exactly you will do it in the firmware is up to you. There are tons of different ways to do it.